# Where to get free benchmarks for CIS CAT Lite in xml format?

Tags: benchmarking, standards-compliance, auditing

i am planning to use CIS CAT Lite (free version) for auditing several RHEL servers. However, Lite version contains only few benchmarks and none of them is for RHEL. My problem is, i can not purchase CIS SecureSuite Membership but also can not use illegaly downloaded stuff. Is there any free source of benchmarks for CIS CAT Lite in XML format? Or any alternative how to get official xml benchmarks for free?

I tried to find benchmarks for CIS CAT Lite on google but without luck. I found free CIS benchmark PDFs but they are useless when you need to audit multiple machines. Also, none of the free memberships for SecureSuite does not apply for my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question about the MacOS-Benchmark as XML and some others which are not included in CIS-Cat Lite.

I asked their support and here is the answer:

> All Benchmarks, including MacOS, are available in machine-readable formats such as XML only with a SecureSuite Membership.
>
> The PDF versions are free to download and use in a noncommercial capacity.